# Can Watto get drunk and blow up Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In *The Phantom Menace*, Anakin talks about having a bomb inside of him and, should he try to escape, Watto can simply blow him up.

> SHMI: All slaves have transmitters placed inside their bodies somewhere.
>
> ANAKIN: I've been working on a scanner to try and locate them, but no 
>   luck.
>
> SHMI: Any attempt to escape...
>
> ANAKIN: ...and they blow you up...poof!

Did they ever remove this bomb or device from Anakin? Did Watto still retain the ability to blow up Anakin?

Comment: What does getting drunk have to do with it?

Comment: @Moyli what doesnt it have to do with it.

Comment: I'd love it if a random Toydorian had the ability to defeat Darth Vader all along

Comment: @armadillo woops, was gana add something, then said na

Comment: I'm tempted to change the title from "***Can** Watto get drunk and blow up Anakin?*" to "***Should** Watto get drunk and blow up Anakin?*". I think we can all agree the answer is yes.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea for a fanfic.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### No, the device was deactivated and later removed.

The Phantom Menace novelization p192-193:

> They went to Watto's shop first, where the Toydarian had completed the
>   forms necessary to assure Anakin's freedom. The transmitter that bound
>   Anakin to his life of slavery was deactivated permanently. It would be
>   removed surgically at a later date. Watto was still grumbling about
>   the unfairness of things as they left him and went back out into the
>   street.

[image: Watto mad]

And from the junior novel (Thanks be to <s>Rich-</s> Valorum, the only person with the book):

> Silently, Qui-Gon fell into step beside him. The Jedi did not speak
>   until the slave quarters were out of sight behind a building. Then he
>   gestured Anakin to the left. “We have to stop at Watto’s shop.”
>   Startled, Anakin looked up. “Why?” “To get your slave transmitter
>   neutralized.” The process didn’t take long, but it left Anakin feeling
>   odd, as if he had suddenly become an entirely new and different
>   person. I never thought not being a slave would feel so strange, he
>   thought as he trudged along beside Qui-Gon.

[image: Watto]